# Connect to Oracle server from local network client

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i want to connect to oracle on IP 192.168.1.18 from a client IP 192.168.1.200 through SQL developer

i setup oracle server on the server

what i must set up on the client except sql developer?

please be patient with me i am beginner using oracle

Answer (score 1):

If you use thin JDBC driver, no need to install Oracle on client machine (JDBC driver is all you need).

Check that your server is running and have listener running ("lsnrctl status" on server side).

in SQL Developper just add new connection and choose Connect

If you can't access it, verify URL syntax, host/port and instance name (or service in DBA_SERVICES)
and be sure no firewall blocks connection

use "tnsping YourDbServer" to verify (part of Oracle client install if available)

 Good luck